# executable file not found in $PATH - Java, Ubuntu, containers

Tags: docker

I want delete containers in docker  (Ubuntu 22.04)

I try like a user, and like a root: otherwise, I get the same result.

```
docker ps -a    
docker container ls
```

exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
Current PATH : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/anatoly

Comment: Show /var/lib/docker,what is inside.

Comment: What the way to show it?

Comment: sudo su -,then got that directory,than ls -la.

Comment: docker# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 сен 30 15:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 4096 сен 30 15:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 сен 30 15:45 cli-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Get Container ID:

```bash
docker ps -a
```

Force delete Container ( will delete it even if it's running)

```bash
docker container rm -f $CONTAINER_ID
```

To seel all other available options:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/

Comment: It is the thing I ask about.

docker ps -a
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
Current PATH : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/anatoly

Answer (score 0):

You must reproduce this
Login as a root

```
sudo su -
```

Go to
cd `/var/lib/docker`

Now if you ls,you should get

```
drwx--x--x   4 root root  4096 феб 27  2022 buildkit
drwx--x--- 101 root root 12288 сеп 23 11:48 containers
drwx------   3 root root  4096 феб 27  2022 image
drwxr-x---   3 root root  4096 феб 27  2022 network
drwx--x--- 879 root root 94208 окт  2 06:52 overlay2
drwx------   4 root root  4096 феб 27  2022 plugins
drwx------   2 root root  4096 окт  2 06:52 runtimes
drwx------   5 root root  4096 окт  2 06:52 swarm
drwx------   2 root root  4096 окт  2 06:52 tmp
drwx------   2 root root  4096 феб 27  2022 trust
drwx-----x  57 root root  4096 окт  2 06:52 volumes
```

You have here whole thruth about containers ,volumes and etc.

Comment: thanks, I was in a process of reinstalling docker.

I did again by this instruction https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#prerequisites
and after paragraph 3 I got:  

sudo service docker start         OK

sudo docker run hello-world                 ERROR 

exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH                    
Current PATH : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/home/anatoly